# Immersive fullscreen on Android 11

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Before, to enable immersive fullscreen mode, you'd have to use `setSystemUiVisibility`, like so:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

As of API 30, it's deprecated, so what's the workaround?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

For compatibility, use `WindowCompat` and `WindowInsetsControllerCompat`. You'll need to upgrade your gradle dependency for `androidx.core` to at least `1.6.0-alpha03` so that there will be support for `setSystemBarsBehavior` on SDK < 30. `mainContainer` is the top-level `ConstraintLayout` in my activity.

```
private fun hideSystemUI() {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, mainContainer).let { controller ->
        controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        controller.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    }
}

private fun showSystemUI() {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, mainContainer).show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
}
```

You can find out more information about `WindowInsets` by watching this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acC7SR1EXsI)

**EDIT:**

I didn't consider display cutouts or in-display cameras in this answer previously. In the app theme style, i added the following to display my content above the cutout (to the top of the screen when in portrait mode):

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

You can read more at this link: [Display Cutout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout)

Comment: I think you mean `1.5.0-alpha05` for the controller compat

Comment: @avalancha You're correct, i just checked release notes https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core I updated the answer thanks

Comment: I found that there may be an issue with setting the `systemBarsBehavior` on some devices using this alpha library. Please see the bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173203649#comment2 *Be sure to star issue for more attention

Comment: This answer is surely needed in future. Need to keep eye on bug fixes in library.

Comment: Is there any way to get back value set by `window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(value)`? Replacement of `(window.decorView.systemUiVisibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN) == 0` @James

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is not working even on Android emulator (API 30). System insets are hidden until I tap the screen for the first time then navigation bar comes back and never leaves in spite of what was set as behaviour.

Comment: @racs did you use the code above or below the *EDIT:*? This is a known bug as mentioned in the post, the library used is still in the alpha stage and the temporary is below the *EDIT:*

Comment: @James I used the one without the compat library (so below EDIT), I checked the SDK version myself.

Comment: In androidx.core Version 1.6.0-alpha03 bug fixes, you can see that this issue is fixed. See its release notes:https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core. Or see:https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173203649

Comment: @ChaitanyaKarmarkar You're right! Add support for setSystemBarsBehavior on SDK < 30 in alpha03. Will update my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, currently I am using it in my app and so far not faced any problems.

Comment: Is `setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)` really needed? I don't see any difference, except that it [breaks action bar](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176380836) on API 29 and below.
And, BTW, there is `WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()` for all bars.

Comment: @gmk57 Good catch with the `systemBars()`, i modified the answer to reflect. I can't answer your first question at the moment.

Comment: @James what is the **mainContainer**?

Comment: @SaurabhDhage Good Question. `mainContainer` is the top-level `ViewGroup` (`ConstraintLayout` in my case) in my activity. I just updated my answer thanks for asking.

Comment: Can someone post a Java version of this with compability, Ive been struggling to get it right last couple of hours.

Comment: @James couldn't we use `window.decorView` to get the root view rather than passing a `ViewGroup`? This would also simplify this call from Fragments, though.

Comment: WindowInsetsControllerCompat not supported SDK > 20

Comment: You should have voted to close this question, instead of duplicating answer here and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64828067/1650674 only minutes apart.

Answer (score 34):

Here's the answer in Kotlin, in case if you don't want to increase the size of your app by using the `androidx` library.

```
private fun setFullscreen() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
        window.insetsController?.apply {
            hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
            systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        }
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION)
    }
}
```

Call the function your activity's `onCreate` method.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

As documentation suggests, you should use `WindowInsetsController`.

```
getWindow().setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
WindowInsetsController controller = getWindow().getInsetsController();
if (controller != null) {
    controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() | WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
    controller.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
}
```

Comment: ok i tried this, but this requires minimum api level 30. So my question is - "What should be implemented for api levels that are below level 30?"

Comment: @MohitYadav you usually do it with an if, such as `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30) { ... here goes the version for old devices ... } else { here comes the newer version }`

Comment: oh ok. I had implemented in the same way, but was confused if there was new way in jetpack.. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any new way which is compatible with old versions too?

Comment: Yes, you can make it compatible with older versions, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64828028/3422470

Comment: Is there any way to get back value set by `window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(value)`? Replacement of `(window.decorView.systemUiVisibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN) == 0` @LeoLeontev

Answer (score 10):

For the deprecation, you can try the below code. Worked for me.

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        final WindowInsetsController controller = getWindow().getInsetsController();

        if (controller != null)
            controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
    }
    else {
        //noinspection deprecation
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
```

Comment: Crashing app In This Code

Comment: Please check again. If the error remains, please share the error

Answer (score 7):

For fullscreen

Hide StatusBar

```
private void hideSystemBars() {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(getWindow().getDecorView());
    if (windowInsetsController == null) {
        return;
    }
    // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
    windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
    // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
}
```

show StatusBar

```
private void showSystemBars() {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(getWindow().getDecorView());
    if (windowInsetsController == null) {
        return;
    }
    // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
    windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
    // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
    windowInsetsController.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
}
```

for top camera cutting in full screen mode

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:ignore="NewApi">shortEdges</item>
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me, mixed two answers:

First create method :

```
private void setFullScreen(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        getWindow().setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
        WindowInsetsController controller = getWindow().getInsetsController();
        if(controller != null) {
            controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() | WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
            controller.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
        }
    }
    else {
        //noinspection deprecation
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
}
```

then on create just call it after setContentView like this :

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        setFullScreen();
    }
```

and it works like a charm :D

Answer (score 4):

**I'm using this one, work perfectly for all Android version**

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
            val controller = window.insetsController
            if (controller != null) {
                controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
                controller.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
            }
        } else {
            // All below using to hide navigation bar
            val currentApiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
            val flags = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)

            // This work only for android 4.4+
            if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = flags
                // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
                // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
                // show up and won't hide
                val decorView = window.decorView
                decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener { visibility: Int ->
                    if (visibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN == 0) {
                        decorView.systemUiVisibility = flags
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Chris Banes @
Android Developers official youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acC7SR1EXsI)
 use following code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var view: View

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
    }

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (hasFocus) hideSystemUI()
    }

    private fun hideSystemUI() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            // Tell the window that we want to handle/fit any system windows
            WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

            val controller = view.windowInsetsController

            // Hide the keyboard (IME)
            controller?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.ime())

            // Sticky Immersive is now ...
            controller?.systemBarsBehavior = BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE

            // When we want to hide the system bars
            controller?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())

            /*val flag = WindowInsets.Type.statusBars()
            WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()
            WindowInsets.Type.captionBar()
            window?.insetsController?.hide(flag)*/
        } else {
            //noinspection
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Sample Link [User interface sample](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/master/WindowInsetsAnimation)

Comment: Your answer is outdated. There's no need to use the deprecated flags in the `else` block. See accepted answer for the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

//you can do it by  the following simple method

```java
public void FullScreencall() {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(8);
  } else {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(InputDeviceCompat.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN);       
  }
}
```