# How to hide the System Ui in Android API 30

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fullscreen, android-navigation-bar

I've recently updated my targetSDK to 30. In this API setSystemUiVisibility is marked as deprecated, despite Android still recommending it ([see here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation)).

How can I go to sticky immersive Fullscreen in this API?

My code before updating:

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Immersive fullscreen on Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643517/immersive-fullscreen-on-android-11)

Comment: @Biscuit yes, thanks!