# I want to disable navigation bar and status bar in Android 11

Tags: java, android

We are creating the app in an Android 11 environment.
To prevent app users from dropping the app or changing settings,
I would like to completely hide or disable the navigation bar and status bar.

View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY

View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE

View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION

View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN

I tried all the descriptions mentioned above on the internet.
It is hidden when you are not touching it, but if you scroll it will appear and you can operate it.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android.view.View.systemUiVisibility deprecated. What is the replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577645/android-view-view-systemuivisibility-deprecated-what-is-the-replacement)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate question.
See here:
[Immersive fullscreen on Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643517/immersive-fullscreen-on-android-11) .
You have to use the "WindowInsetsController" for Android verions >= 11.