# Layout behind statusbar

Tags: android

I try to have my layout behind my statusbar.

How can I do it with Android R ?

Before I used this solution but now it's deprecated :

```
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
```

And the result is :
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android.view.View.systemUiVisibility deprecated. What is the replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577645/android-view-view-systemuivisibility-deprecated-what-is-the-replacement)

Comment: Not really, I don't get the same result because the bottom is truncated...

Comment: Would you please check is there any similarity  ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68887853/prevent-the-layout-from-resizing-in-android

Comment: No similarity to sorry